# Implement deferred deeplinking framework for ios

Tags: ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement a framework like branch.io or firebase/dynamicLink for deferred deeplinking. Where I can get tutorial for that or the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deferred deep linking, Branch has the best out of the box solution. This is because Branch links provide a response body of data in the form of a json object that you can parse accordingly. Firebase forces you to embed your data in the form of query params and it gets really messy. Branch also covers a significant amount more edge cases. To get started with Branch Universal links check out [Branch's iOS docs](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/).

Comment: I implemented a poc. It is working fine on iOS 11 but not working on ios 10. not getting param.

Comment: @AashishNagar Could you provide a bit more information about your implementation? If it's working on iOS 11 it should almost certainly be working on iOS 10 as well